# @AfterReturning aspect executes in same transaction of pointcut method?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, aspect

I have a requirement to do a task after execution of a function. I have used Aspect for this. but I have some confusion.

I have a function A() in a spring service.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false,
               isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT,
               propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED,
               rollbackFor = {Exception.class})
void A() {
 //Do Something
}
```

I have an `@Afterreturning` aspect on this function.

```
 @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(Sevice.saverecord(..)) ")
 public void processNotifications(JoinPoint jp) {}
```

I want to know whether this aspect will use the transaction of metod A() or it will create a new transaction automatically. As I have not defined any transaction on this aspect method.

I tried to print the transaction detail using TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().toString() in both method.I got two different IDs.

Can anybody explain Does it mean there are two transactions, If yes where this second transaction came from?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes** the `@AfterReturning` aspect executes in the same transaction as that of the advised method.

The execution sequence while invoking a transactional method is depicted in below diagram (*ref - spring [docs](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained)*)

[image: Spring Transaction Flow]

The aspect (*i.e. custom advisor*) can be configured to run before or after the transaction advice, which by default is *after*.

For further reference on how to configure the custom advisor to run before the transaction advice make use of the [`Ordered`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Ordered.html) as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-applying-more-than-just-tx-advice).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just had another doubt. If I use new transaction (REQUIRES_NEW) on afterReturning() function, it does not start a new transaction instead it picks the old one.

Comment: Yes that's expected, since the advice and target method are enclosed within same transaction it will continue with existing i.e. old one. You can explore [PROPAGATION_NESTED](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation-nested) for your scenario.

Comment: I am using JpaTransactionManager in my application and  PROPAGATION_NESTED is not supported with this transactionManager. 
I get the following error: org.springframework.transaction.NestedTransactionNotSupportedException: JpaDialect does not support savepoints - check your JPA provider's capabilities. 
Is there any other alternative that can be used here to implement something like 'Whenever any exception occur from db layer rollback should happen to a specific savepoint only.

Comment: You should switch to [DataSourceTransactionManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceTransactionManager.html) instead for save-point support

Comment: Also if the save-point is end of the advised method you can simply swallow the exception in aspect (*though not so elegant thing to do*) without changing the transaction manager

Comment: But If any RunTimeException like SQLGrammerException, UniqueConstrainViolationException occurs at data base level (e.g. at query.getResult() ), In that case Rollbackproperty of transaction has already been set to true by framework before exception comes to the service layer. So even you swallow the exception in your code transaction will be rolled back. Is this a expected behaviour ? I think changing the TransactionManger is only solution.

Comment: correct the rollback will occur in the mentioned scenario; it's better to switch to the `DataSourceTransactionManager`