# Transaction does not commit when advise starts its execution

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-aop

I am writing an aspect which will send email on save/update/delete operations with old and updated data as the email information. I am using `JpaRepository` provided by the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency.
I am using `@Transactional` on these operations! I want that the aspect i have written for email should be called after the transaction is committed. But its not working that way. Aspect is also executed within the transaction boundary.

Below is the aspect.

```java
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class EmailAspect {

  private EmailSender emailSender;

  public EmailAspect( EmailSender emailSender) {
    this.emailSender = emailSender;
  }

  @Around("execution(* com.company.app.service.*Repository.save*(..))")
  public void sendEmail(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    Object myCustomObject= joinPoint.proceed();
    emailSender.send("Testing from app - Subject","Testing from app - Body", "test@test.com");
  }

}
```

Comment: Please go through these two SO questions and their answers , [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39406242/4214241) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23651464/4214241)

Comment: [TransactionalEventListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/event/TransactionalEventListener.html) could be a good alternative here

Comment: Two ideas if you want to stick with Spring AOP: (1) Try an `@After` (runs regardless of possible exceptions thrown by your methods) or `@AfterReturning` (runs only if the corresponding method returns normally) advice instead of `@Around`. I have not tested this with `@Transactional`, but there is a chance that it works. (2) If all else fails, you can still send the e-mail in a separate thread in order to not unnecessarily drag on the transaction. If this comment helps, please let me know and I will convert it into an answer.

Comment: Two people tried to help you, yet there is no feedback. Please be so polite as to reply so we all know if someone should write an answer which you can accept in order to close the question or if there is any follow-up problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: @R.G thanks for the first link [Ordered](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Ordered.html) solved my problem